# How get the product SKU in XML magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, xml, stock, manage-stock

I want to create a product XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <stocks>
        <product>
            <sku>883503536128</sku>
            <eansku>883503536128</eansku>
            <stock>982</stock>
        </product>
    </stocks>
</root>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on: https://gist.github.com/Nolwennig/b67bbbcba359c04fe77df9393dc3907a

You can put this script in root directory, aside of `app/`

```
<?php
if(php_sapi_name() != 'cli')
{
    die('only via cli');
}
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
Mage::app('admin');
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
/* @var $resource Mage_Core_Model_Resource */
$conn = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
/* @var $conn Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'export';
if(!is_dir($dir))
{
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}
$newFile = $dir . DS . 'product.xml';
$tmpFile = $newFile . '.tmp';
$fp = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'."\n");
fwrite($fp, '<root>'."\n");
fwrite($fp, '<stocks>'."\n");
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $_product)
{
    fwrite($fp, '<product>'."\n");
    fwrite($fp, '  <sku><![CDATA['.$_product->getSku().']]></sku>'."\n");
    fwrite($fp, '  <eansku><![CDATA['.$_product->getEansku().']]></eansku>'."\n");
    fwrite($fp, '  <stock>'.$_product->getQty().'</stock>'."\n");
    fwrite($fp, '</product>'."\n");
}
fwrite($fp, '</stocks>'."\n");
fwrite($fp, '</root>'."\n");
fclose($fp);
@unlink($newFile);
rename($tmpFile, $newFile);
```

### I write this quickly, without test and just a quick final checking. Test and review before run that.

Comment: where i put this file in magento ?

Comment: in root directory, aside of `app/`

Comment: Can you please explain how it work ?

Comment: Get the 39 lines of code and paste this in a file. Call your file `product.xml_generator.php`, for example. After that, put the file on your magento server, to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

> Get the list of products you want to include in the XML file. For example, if you want to include all enabled products, then:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
);
```

Then loop through all products and put the required attributes in the XML file.

Note: To know how to create XML file programmatically, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php